# Data sorting in a dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

First of all, thank you a lot for what you are doing here. That is very nice.

I am developing a web application with Dojo, and I am facing a problem with ordering my rows in a `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid`.
Let's say i have a product with product status, my JSON file looks like:

```
[
  {"id":1,"name":"Car A","price":"1000","productstatus":{"id":1,"name":"new"}},
  {"id":2,"name":"Car B","code":"2000","productstatus":{"id":2,"name":"old"}}
]
```

I want to put that data in my grid and change the order of the rows by clicking in the header.

I have in my HTML file:

```
<table id="lstProduct" jsId="lstProduct" dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th field="id">Id</th>
      <th field="name" width="100px">Name</th>
      <th field="price" width="100px">Price</th>
      <th field="id" formatter="formatterStatus">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

and my Javascript file:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

  productStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: { items: ${products} }});
  dijit.byId("lstProduct").setStore(productStore);

});

// formatter
function formatterStatus(val, rowIndex) {
  return lstTasks.getItem(rowIndex)['productstatus'][0]['name'];
}
```

The problem? I cannot order by status (status's `name`), it only orders by `product.id` when I click in the status header.

Any workaround for that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add `clientSort="true"` to enable client-side sorting.  Add this to the `<table>` declaration.